# Copy resources to a Dockerfile from another Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I've seen many examples how to get an access to another build within one Dockerfile like here:
https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds

```
FROM golang:1.7.3 as builder
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/
RUN go get -d -v golang.org/x/net/html  
COPY app.go    .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o app .

FROM alpine:latest  
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
WORKDIR /root/
COPY --from=builder /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/app .
CMD ["./app"]
```

Here is used COPY --FROM=builder

But can I get an access somehow, if I split the build into 2 Dockerfiles, from one to another?

When I do that it says: "failed to build: invalid from flag value client: pull access denied. repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'" How to get around it?

Answer (score 2):

[The Dockerfile documentation for `COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) says, in part:

> Optionally `COPY` accepts a flag `--from=<name|index>` that can be used to set the source location....  In case a build stage with a specified name can’t be found an image with the same name is attempted to be used instead.

So if you build your first half

```
docker build -t gena/app-builder -f Dockerfile.builder .
```

Then in the second half Dockerfile you should be able to

```
COPY --from=gena/app-builder /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/app .
```

Comment: So, as I got it, I can refer to the previous build stages only within one Dockerfile ?